# What is the proper use of the word "state of the art"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

I am a bit confused with using the phrase *state of the art*. Is the following usage correct?

> My motivation relies on the fact, discussed above, that there is **little global 
>        state of the art evaluation** of this product.

Comment: I don't see why this was closed. The questioner did identify a specific source of concern in the text (i.e., the appropriateness of the term "state of the art").

Answer (score 1):

This usage appears incorrect. The product may be state of the art (or not), the *evaluation* cannot be described as little-global or state of the art.

I think you meant,

> My motivation relies on the fact, discussed above, that there has been *limited* evaluation of this *state of the art* product.

Comment: evaluation can be state of the art? if the product is new

Comment: @sacvf Context is key; if you're describing a new method of evaluation then maybe. The product being evaluated is then immaterial (except as a point of comparison with other evaluation methods). How is the age of the product relevant for the evaluation of the product?

Comment: @sacvf What is the question? Evaluate is a verb.

Comment: I do not understand what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the evaluation being state-of-the-art, it would help to surround the article with a little disambiguation.

> My motivation relies on the fact, discussed above, that of the evaluations conducted of this product, few can be considered state-of-the-art.

I would just say 'recent', though.